# Nginx Controller in Kubernetes: Handshaking to upstream - peer closed connection in SSL handshake

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

On a local environment built with kubeadm. The cluster is made of Master and 2 worker nodes.

**What it is failing:**

Exposing Nginx-ingress Controller to external by Service type LoadBalancer, trying TLS termination to the Kubernetes cluster.

Here the exposed Service:

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      
nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.101.5.75     192.168.1.82   80:30745/TCP,443:30092/TCP   
web-service     ClusterIP      10.101.26.176   <none>         8080/TCP
```

**What it's working:**

Able to reach the web application with HTTP port 80 from external.

Here the pods in the cluster:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE    
nginx-ingress-7c5588544d-4mw9d    1/1     Running   0          38m   10.44.0.2   node1   
web-deployment-7d84778bc6-52pq7   1/1     Running   1          19h   10.44.0.1   node1   
web-deployment-7d84778bc6-9wwmn   1/1     Running   1          19h   10.36.0.2   node2
```

**Test result for TLS termination**

Client side:

```
curl -k https://example.com -v
* Rebuilt URL to https://example.com/
*   Trying 192.168.1.82...
* Connected to example.com (192.168.1.82) port 443 (#0)
* found 127 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 513 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification SKIPPED
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: example.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #1
*    subject: CN=example.com
*    start date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 16:33:49 GMT
*    expire date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 16:33:49 GMT
*    issuer: CN=My Cert Authority
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: nginx/1.19.3
```

Server side (logs from nginx-ingress pod):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: example.com
X-Real-IP: 10.32.0.1
X-Forwarded-For: 10.32.0.1
X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*

2020/10/22 18:38:59 [error] 23#23: *12 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking  to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.44.0.1:8081/", host: "example.com"

2020/10/22 18:38:59 [warn] 23#23: *12 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.32.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.44.0.1:8081/", host: "example.com"

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.19.3
```

**What i checked**

Generated a CA and Server certificate following the link:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/PREREQUISITES/#tls-certificates

Checked the server certificate and the server key under /etc/nginx/secrets/default of the nginx-ingress Pod and they look correct. Here the output of the resource VirtualServer:

```
NAME         STATE   HOST          IP             PORTS      AGE
vs-example   Valid   example.com   192.168.1.82   [80,443]   121m
```

**VirtualServer:**

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: vs-example
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  host: example.com
  tls:
    secret: example-tls
  upstreams:
  - name: example
    service: web-service
    port: 8080
    tls:
      enable: true
  routes:
  - path: /v2
    action:
      pass: example
  routes:
  - path: /
    action:
      pass: example
```

**Secret**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: example-tls
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  tls.crt: (..omitted..)
  tls.key: (..omitted..)
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

**Nginx.conf**

Here an extract of the nginx.conf taken from the running Pod:

```
server {
    # required to support the Websocket protocol in VirtualServer/VirtualServerRoutes
    set $default_connection_header "";
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/secrets/default;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/secrets/default;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens "on";
```

Cannot find what's in going on when trying to reach the web application with HTTPS.

Comment: From the logs, it looks like the request is passed on to the upstream `"https://10.44.0.1:8081/"`, is that correct?

Comment: 10.44.0.1 is the ip address assigned to the webapplication Pod on node1. 8081 is the listening port on the container of the web application

Comment: And port 8081 is for https traffic? I’m thinking it could be a http vs https problem.

Comment: No. I would expect https on 10.44.0.2 that is the ingress controller Pod indeed

Comment: adding "ingressClassName: nginx-ingress" in VirtualServer solves the SSL issue. no more errors in nginx-ingress pod logs. Now 404 is returned to the client

Comment: Ok. Now it is working, i'm going to update my question. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working.

Comment: Yes thanks, you cleared me about the configuration

Comment: @Marco_81 Don't update the question with the answer. Provide the anawer in answers section and mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several errors in the VirtualServer, edited with these changes solved the problem:

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: vs-example
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  host: example.com
  tls:
    secret: example-tls

  upstreams:
  - name: example
    service: web-service
    port: 8080
#    tls:            --> this caused the SSL issue in the upstream
#      enable: true

  routes:
  - path: /
    action:
      pass: example
  - path: /v1
    action:
      pass: example
```

accessing web application with HTTPS now works